# Sorting a list of numAlpha strings

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of strings that contain a numeric & alpha sequence. I want to first sort by number and then by alpha such as 1a, 2b, 4, 77c, 743, etc.

I've been playing around with the following javascript and I'm close to banging my head off the wall. Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
var a1 = ["4a", "4c", "1a", "4b", "13c", "4a", "1a", "11c", "112c", "12", "9"];

var a2 = a1.sort(function(a, b) {

  if (a.slice(-1) == "a" || a.slice(-1) == "b" || a.slice(-1) == "c") {
    var charPart = [a.slice(-1), b],
      numPart = [a.slice(0, a.length - 1), b];
    if (b.slice(-1) == "a" || b.slice(-1) == "b" || b.slice(-1) == "a") {
      var charPart = [a.slice(-1), b.slice(-1)],
        numPart = [a.slice(0, a.length - 1), b.slice(0, b.length - 1)];
    }
  }


  if (numPart[0] < numPart[1]) return -1;
  else if (numPart[0] > numPart[1]) return 1;
  else if (numPart[0] == numPart[1]) return -1;
  else {
    if (charPart[0] < charPart[1]) return -1;
    else if (charPart[0] > charPart[1]) return 1
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fRsD/307/

Comment: What is the desired result you want in `a2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for splitting the strings with lookahead for non numeric values.

For example `'13c'` becomes after splitting `['13', 'c']`.

In the callback, the value or the default value like the empty string is used for comparison.

```js
var a1 = ["4a", "4c", "1a", "4b", "13c", "4a", "1a", "11c", "112c", "12", "9"];
  
a1.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.split(/(?=\D)/),
        bb = b.split(/(?=\D)/);
    return aa[0] - bb[0] || (aa[1] || '').localeCompare(bb[1] || '');
});
console.log(a1);
```

Comment: Gah! I misread the input data and though there were some with the letters and numbers reversed; they don't seem to be, so this is much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to sort first by the (first) numeric part in each string, and then within entries that have the same numeric value, by the (first) alpha part of the string, this does it — see comments:

```js
var a1 = ["4a", "4c", "1a", "4b", "13c", "4a", "1a", "11c", "112c", "12", "9"];
a1.sort(function(l, r) {
  var lnum = l.match(/\d+/);
  var rnum = r.match(/\d+/);
  if (lnum && rnum) {
    // We have numbers, compare them
    lnum = +lnum[0];
    rnum = +rnum[0];
    if (lnum != rnum) {
      // Not the same, put the smaller one first
      return lnum - rnum;
    }
  }
  
  // Either no numbers, or they match; use alpha
  var lalpha = l.match(/\D+/);
  var ralpha = r.match(/\D+/);
  if (lalpha && ralpha) {
    // We have alpha, return result of comparing them
    return lalpha[0].localeCompare(ralpha[0]);
  }
  
  // Neither numbers or alpha; give up
  return 0;
});
console.log(a1);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @whoquestionmark: No worries. If the numbers always come before the letters, as in the sample data, then Nina's answer is the simpler way to go. For some reason I thought I'd seen some with the letters first (e.g., `a1` rather than `1a`), but they aren't there, so...